# Find multiple SQL columns and update based on defined data listed in query

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have an update query in which I am trying to locate data in a column from a single table. All while taking other defined data listed in the query to update another column in the same table once a match has been found with that original search. Below is an example of my update statement. My end goal is to find '003447710' then update AltId to '540112'

```
UPDATE Site

SET AltId = ('540112'
'540129'
'540142'
'540143')

WHERE CCMFStatus in ('003447710',
'002754540',
'003564370',
'005942870')
```

I am sure there may already be something like this out there but I am really having trouble on an easy method on how to do this quickly and accurately.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
    update site 
    set altid = a.altid 
    from 
     (select altid,CCMFstatus from site) as a 
    where site.CCMFstatus = a.CCMFstatus
```

Comment: if you are updating too many rows then you can use limit option with this

Answer (score 0):

The best way might be multiple `update` statements:

```
UPDATE Site
    SET AltId = '540112'
    WHERE CCMFStatus = '003447710';
```

And so on.

If not, you can do this with a giant case statement or a `join`:

```
WITH values as (
      SELECT '003447710' as oldstatus, '540112' as newaltid UNION ALL
      SELECT '002754540', '540129' UNION ALL
      SELECT '003564370', '540142' UNION ALL
      SELECT '005942870', '540143'
     )
UPDATE s
    SET AltId = va.newaltid
    FROM site s JOIN
         values v
         ON s.CCMFStatus = v.oldstatus;
```

If you already have the values in a table, then you don't need the `WITH` statement.  You can just use the table.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using CASE statement?

```
UPDATE SITE SET AltID = (CASE 

WHEN CCMFStatus = '003447710' THEN '540112'
WHEN CCMFStatus = '002754540' THEN '540129'
END)

WHERE 

CCMFStatus in ('003447710', '002754540', '003564370', '005942870');
```

BR,